# Is there an editor in windows that automatically saves constantly?

Tags: windows, editor

I'm looking for a editor in windows that constantly saves file.

In linux I do
cat>somefile

and then just start typing.  somefile gets filled up as I type.

Is there editor or similar thing in WIndows?  Preferably a non-dos tool?

Answer (score 0):

I use WebStorm from JetBrains, which saves constantly and unobtrusively.

I really love it. I use it as a text editor and for my web development.

http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

(and no I don't work there).

Comment: Thanks!  I looked at Word and there is some save feature but I believe minimum interval is every minute.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to install some unix features to windows.
Have a look at [this](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) CoreUtils

Comment: Do you think these tools will work with windows speech recognition?  Basically to the editor or to cat I would like to use speech to txt.

Answer (score 0):

The shareware text editor [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultraedit.html) by default works with using a temporary file which means create a copy of the file to edit in directory `%TEMP%` and copy this temporary file on save back to original file. The usage of a temporary file makes it possible to use *Undo* and *Redo*.

But it is possible at **Advanced - Configuration - File Handling - Temporary Files** to disable the usage of a temporary file for all files or just for large files depending on a threshold value in KB. All edits made on a file opened without usage of a temporary file are permanent which means immediately done on storage media.

Another feature of UltraEdit is automatic save in regular intervals which can be configured at **Advanced - Configuration - File Handling - Save** with or without making a backup on every save and even supporting version backups which means backups with an incrementing number on every save.

Last but not least on usage of a temporary file for editing a file as by default UltraEdit can recover last edits if UltraEdit crashes (uedit32.exe process killed with Windows task manager), or Windows crashes, or a sudden power loss occurs. The temporary file is updated quite often in the background by UltraEdit and therefore the restore on next start after an unexpected end of the editing session often restores nearly all edits made last on a file. The recovery feature includes also new files not being saved ever as file with a file name.

It would be interesting to know for offering a perhaps better solution why you want that any edit is immediately written to the file. In general this is the opposite of what users want on editing a text file and is not good on some storage medias like SSD hard disks.